# Why does this not compile

Tags: java, javac

I am trying to play with Java to understand operator precedence. Based on what I have read I think the following code should work:

```
System.out.println(("" + (1--2)));
```

I believe it should be evaluated in this order:

- (1--2) becomes 3
- ("" + 3) becomes "3"
- System.out.println("3")

So I expect it to print 3 but it does not appear to be legal code. Can someone explain where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: `(1--2) = 3 not -1`. BTW what is the error you have got? I dont think the error come from this line

Comment: The compiler requires spaces or brackets for the `(1--2)` part. Without these, the compiler thinks you are asking for a post-decrement, and then it doesn't understand why there's a 2 afterwards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to type it like so:

```
System.out.println(("" + (1-(-2))))
```

"--" is not recognized as a valid operator in this instance so it's causing a compiler error. Also, it will return 3, not -1.

Edit: As mentioned, another way to type this is with a space in between the "-" like so:

```
System.out.println(("" + (1 - -2)))
```

Comment: You can also use `(1 - -2)`. The spaces are enough for the compiler to understand what is required.

Comment: Yes. Essentially @FMC chose incorrect syntax for what he wants to do. Your deduction for operator precedence is otherwise correct.

Comment: Makes sense.  The compiler resolves `--` to post-decrement, then has no operator left over to tell it what to do with the 2.

Comment: @Jason or just `(1- -2)`. No need for space after  the 1.

Comment: @markspace but also you can't decrement an integer literal. It's not simply that "there's nothing left over".

Comment: `--` is an operator, just not the operator he wants

Comment: @AndyTurner true, but while there is no *need*, it's easier to read when spaced apart. I prefer readability over brevity.

Answer (score 3):

Java reads  `--` as a decrement operator, meaning that it needs to be attached to a variable for proper syntax, not next to a literal. You can fix this by simply putting a space in between the two `-`symbols,  i.e. `System.out.println(("" + (1- -2)));`